# IPv4 subnet (aka CIDR/"cider") compact notation: any RFC?

Tags: networking, ip, rfc

I've seen around IPv4 subnet address ranges expressed in a compact form.

For example:

```
127/24      == 127.0.0.0/24
10/8        == 10.0.0.0/8
10.10.10/24 == 10.10.10.0/24
```

BTW I can't find any RFC (or any other kind of official or semi-official documentation) that describes it.

Does anyone have some links to share?

Comment: No, there is no such RFC, but there are some RFCs that use that notation in the RFCs

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks for confirming! I wasn't really able to find any RFC. Could you provide any link to RFCs that use that notation?

Comment: I found one. _[RFC 3927, Dynamic Configuration of IPv4 Link-Local Addresses](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3927)_: "_This document describes how a host may automatically configure an interface with an IPv4 address within the **169.254/16** prefix that is valid for communication with other devices connected to the same physical (or logical) link._" I have seen this notation in various RFCs, but there is no standard for representing IPv4 addresses the way RFC 5952 does for IPv6.

Comment: @RonMaupin thank you! Much appreciated!

Comment: I just saw that _[RFC 1918, Address Allocation for Private Internets](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918)_ lists: `10/8 prefix`, `172.16/12 prefix`, and `192.168/16 prefix`.

Answer (score 0):

I recall this notation being used on Juniper routers as far back as 2001; not sure what, if any, RFC defined it.  RFCs do not define the whole planet; somehow over the years they replaced specifications (which are/were much more detailed), but were originally intended for Request For Comments.  (Gee, I wonder why there are so many bugs in networking gear.)